# Samba not found, where is the samba binary?

Tags: linux, debian, samba

Where is samba by default?

I started samba with:

```
/etc/init.d/samba start
```

But I wanted to check the version with `samba -v`

So I noticed it wasn't in my path and I needed to create a symlink to it at `/usr/bin` or the like.

But I could not find the binary?

I tried: `find -name "samba"` and checked in all the locations and could not find the binary?

Comment: And if you do not find it, you will have to install it: sudo apt-get install samba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Samba binary is called `smbd`.

Check for `/usr/local/sbin/smbd`, `/usr/sbin/smbd` or just use `which smbd` to find it.

Comment: And often `/etc/init.d/samba` is just a script, and hence a text file, which you can peek into to find more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the version of samba using:

`smbstatus`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: While this might have solved your problem, it's not the answer to your original question. Please see http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers if Oliver's post did answer that original question.

Comment: (@Jawa, this was the OP answering their own question. Well, [typical XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I guess...)

Comment: correct, it is unrelated but I feel it is useful passes by none-the-less, any problems let me know.